# jQuery: Ajax - How to find last but one Call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Brief:

To insert the data into Database, I am using asynchronous methodology using jQuery ajax methods, As these calls count is not known how many requests will be sent, i am using the ajaxStop method to identify that the calls are over.

Problem:

My need and problem is: After all the calls are over and inserted the data into the database, i need to find out those inserted records count, So i am trying to add a function or call inside the ajaxStop() method, which actually triggers after all the Ajax calls or completed.  As this will be triggered after all the ajax calls inside the document, When i make a call this will be triggered and again and again which becomes infinite loop.

1. What is the way that i can get the total records after all the
   asynchronous calls are completed or
2. can i find out last but one call so that i can pull the records how
   many are inserted.
3. Is there any other way to achieve this.

I am using jQuery Ajax functions as follows:

```
<script>
//Declaration of function that will insert data into database
    $.ajaxSetup({
      url: "senddata.php"
    });

 function senddata(filename,query,t){
    var file = filename;
    var q = query;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {file,q,t},
            async: true,
            success: function(html){
                 $( '#responce' ).append( '<li>' + html + '</li>');
            },
            error:function(exception){ alert('Exeption:'+exception); }
        })
        }

        $( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
            $.post('senddataQuery.php', { num: 5 }, function(result) { 
                 //alert(result); 
                 $( '#responce' ).append( '<li>' +result+ '</li>');
            });
        });
</script>
```

Suggestions and guidance is welcome.

Appreciate and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like adding a global variable array with each success function pushing its signature:

```js
var ajaxFunctions = [];
var file = filename;
var q = query;
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  data: {file, q, t},
  async: true,
  success: function(html) {
    ajaxFunctions.push("Success1");
    $('#responce').append('<li>' + html + '</li>');
  },
  error: function(exception) {
    alert('Exeption:' + exception);
  }
})
}

$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
  $.post('senddataQuery.php', {
    num: 5
  }, function(result) {
    ajaxFunctions.push("Success2");
    //alert(result); 
    $('#responce').append('<li>' + result + '</li>');
  });
});
```

As simple as that, if you wanna get the last function that gets executed, you can always get:

```
console.log(ajaxFunctions[ajaxFunctions.length - 1]);
```

Comment: Yes I was going to say that he needs to update something in the DOM on every ajax success, otherwise how would he keep track of the records inserted.

Comment: @garek007 Yep... We both think alike.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar, Thank you for your response, I need to act dynamically on the last but one call or last call since i need to get the total count of the inserted data to get. Once after completion of all calls if you want to know the last but one we will come to know as you mentioned but i need to identify dynamically and apply some action over there to get the desired count. Please correct me if i am missing anything from your response.

Comment: @UmadharM if you store the records in a global JS variable then you can act on that variable in your last call